# Correct MySQL query for multi table delete in Python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Looking to be able to delete a message and any comments associated with it from a link on my page. From searching, I believe I might need to do an ON DELETE CASCADE in my python code? However, I'm not too sure how to go about it? This is the last query I tried

```
@app.route('/messages/<id>/delete')
def delete_message(id):

    query = 'DELETE FROM messages WHERE id = :id AND comments WHERE id = :id'
    data = {'id':id}
    mysql.query_db(query,data)

    return redirect('/wall')
```

Tables

```
USERS
id
first_name
last_name
email
pw_hash

MESSAGES
id
messages
user_id

COMMENTS
id 
comments
message_id
user_id
```

Any suggestions on how to write this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. However, it's not something you do in your Python code but a matter of the right settings when you design your database.
If we just focus on your tables `messages` and `comments`, the `comments` table has a foreign key relation to messages, that means the field `message_id` is linked to the field `messages.id`. This doesn't happen automatically, but in your DB-Admintool (e.g phpMyAdmin, HeidiSQL) you need to set this foreign key. And on this foreign key you can set the `ON DELETE` option to `CASCADE` in order to have your comments deleted when you delele the message.

Then your query

```
query = 'DELETE FROM messages WHERE id = :id'
```

will delete the message with that id and automatically also all comments for that message.

I think http://webdevzoom.com/create-edit-delete-foreign-key-phpmyadmin/ might help with some more explanations and illustrations.

Comment: @jps-Thanks! I went and redid my schema and added the CASCADE to it, and it works great.